# Unable to get grunt to run any task

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

Very new to this, sorry.
I'm running node.js v6.9.5 npm 4.2.0. 
Installed grunt-cli on Windows 10.

And this is where I think I've gone wrong, I did `npm install -g grunt-init` which has created a node_modules folder in C:\User[my name]\AppDate\Roaming directory.

I've since uninstalled this using `npm uninstall grunt --save`.

I created the following package.jason in my project root:

```
{
  "name": "manifest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

run npm install which created a new node_modules directory in my project root.

Create a Gruntfile.js containing the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask('speak', function() {

        console.log('hello');

    })   
}
```

But when I run `grunt speak` I'm getting the message:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Warning: Task "speak" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: `registerTask` method of `grunt` has constructor `(taskName, description, taskFunction)`, so maybe you should also add the description of the task in order to make it work?

Edit: Nevermind, I was wrong. Found the source code and if description is null then the function is taken as second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to get round this by totally uninstalling grunt, grunt-cli, npm and node.js, and reinstalling them all from scratch.